# Maths assistance for my excel formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence issue. nth term = number. we are starting with $n=1.$

$4,8,11,14,18,21,24,28,31,34,38.$

So the differences are $4,3,3,4,3,3,4,3,3,4.$ I can confirm that it will continue to follow the same pattern.

the next differences then are $-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1.$

The first things I notice is that there is a basic $3n$ in there

So my initial sequence-$3n= 1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4$

the difference being $1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0$

so there is a looping pattern of $+1$ every 3rd $n$ and I have no idea how to express this, as I haven't done maths in a long time. Any corrections in my logic or a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?  do you want a simple excel command that recursively generates $a_n$, the $n^{th}$ term in the sequence?

Comment: maybe add the value of the check n mod 3 ==1 ?

Comment: If that's all you want then $a_1=4$, $a_n=a_{n-1}+\text {If(mod(n-1,3)=1, 4,3)}$.

Comment: I want to understand the mathmatical formula to produce that sequence. If I knew the maths, then I could convert it into an excel formula. I can obviously type the next numbers with ease. But I want to be able to do say number 182. But I don't want to work out each number to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  *[floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ might be useful.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)_{n\geq 1}=(0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,\ldots)\\
> &\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor\right)_{n\geq 1}=(0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,\ldots)\\
> &\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor+1\right)_{n\geq 1}=(1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,\ldots)\\
> &\left(3n+\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor+1\right)_{n\geq 1}=(4,8,11,14,18,21,24,28,31,\ldots)\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly!!! My formula =ROUNDDOWN(SUM(B8*3)+SUM((B8+1)/3)+1,0). I gave you an up arrow, but it doesn't show as I have no rep!

Comment: @AdamHurrell:You're welcome and congrats, the formulas are equivalent. :-)